# jQuery watermark plugin - basic compatibility question

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

So far I have it implemented, but it only seems to work in Chrome browser, not in Firefox or Internet Explorer. Is this the case or am I missing something...It seems strange there is no compatibility information (that I can find!) on that site...

And for a seeminly popular plugin to not work on 2 major browsers like that seems odd. And I am guessing that all it is doing is changing css styles, so I can't imagine why that shouldn't work on all browsers.

Cheers,

**edit**: Code I was using

```
<html>

<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.watermark.js"></script>

</head>



<body>



<script type="text/javascript">



$(function () {

    $("#tb").watermark("wwww");

});

</script>



<input type="search" id="tb"/>
```

Comment: I downloaded the project from the link you provided and opened the demo and that works for me in FF3.6 and IE7. Does the demo work for you? Can you paste your code to jsfiddle or something so i can try to identify what the problem is.

Comment: It works for me in FF3.6 and IE 7+8 as well

Comment: It works for me too, but password fields don't behave correctly in FF4 and IE8. In FF, it messes up the location of my tiptip (plugin), and also changes the width of the textbox, and in IE I get a script error when the password fields gets focus.  I think it's to do with native support.  If you disable native support, it stops working correctly even in Chrome.